# Reading someone's Minecraft server files using FTP

Tags: networking, ftp, minecraft

I'm having this fun idea:

Is it possible to first retrieve a big Minecraft server's IP address (by pinging the server's IP address like `ping play.cubecraftgames.net`)
and then when you have retrieved the server's IP address connecting to it using your browser (ftp.'IP address') or using [FileZilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla) with 'anonymous' as username and no password so you can only just read the files?

Or is this not possible so you're not able to take a look at the directory?

Comment: It is possible only if the server is massively misconfigured.

Comment: Also, why would you use FTP to the IP adress. Why involve ping at all?   `ftp play.cubecraftgames.net` would have worked just as well.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot.
Think of the server IP-address as the physical address of a house. Sure, when you have the address, you can go there, but if you do not have a key, you won't get past the front door.